# Is this the proper way to set a frame for a CAShapeLayer?

Tags: swift, drag, cashapelayer, bounds

My goal is to get shapes I can drag abound the view, but first am trying to figure out if this is the correct way to set the frame so that a `CAShapeLAyer's` frame is not all zeros and so I can later drag it with touch events.

Below is the code in my class (DrawOVerlay - DO) which is used for a `UIView` on my `Viewcontroller`:

```
 private func drawArc(user c: CGContext) {

    c.setLineCap(.round)
    c.setLineWidth(35.0)

    c.addArc(center: CGPoint(x:187.5,y:200), radius: 90.0, startAngle: -0.5 * .pi, endAngle: (-0.5 * .pi) + (3 / 2 * .pi ), clockwise: false)

    c.replacePathWithStrokedPath()

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.frame = bounds
    shape.path = c.path
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    shape.lineWidth = 1

    print("DO Bounds before:\(String(describing: shape.bounds))")
    print("DO Frame before:\(String(describing: shape.frame))")

    print("DO BoundingBox:\(String(describing: shape.path?.boundingBox))")

    shape.bounds = (shape.path?.boundingBox)!

    print("DO Bounds after:\(String(describing: shape.bounds))")
    print("DO Frame Width:\(String(describing: shape.frame))")

    self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
}
```

The print statements are giving me the correct coordinates for the shape's `bounds` and `frame`, but I'm new to Swift and not sure this is the proper way to go about it.

And then, how do I use this information with touch events to drag the shape layer without flickering?